# how to create simple admin login form without sign up in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a web application, I need a simple Admin Login form without sign up functionality 
I mean basically login form contains only email, password and remember me option. after I login successfully admin goes to dashboard(i have that form )

for example: my login form would be

```
 if email = user@example.com and password = s3cR3TpAsS* encrypted(hard coded)
```

Can anybody help me how to do this functionality?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaah,  I got this solution, Basically we can be done by this problem by adding
 [seed data](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data?autoplay=true)

To do this we all need `seed.rb` file

this can be get by executing following command

```
rake seeder
```

and after that

```
mate seeder
```

and open `seed.rb` file enter following code

```
User.create(name: 'admin',email: 'admin@example.com', password: 's3cR3TpAsS',password_confirmation: 's3cR3TpAsS')
```

For hard code password using bcrypt gem to digestion password and for remember check box functionality remember digestion functionality

I Hope this might help someone

Thanks!